# CustomScrollView could not scroll in the second time entry in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am a beginner of flutter, today I encount a problem that when the second time open the article detail page, the `CustomScrollView` could not scroll and has no error output. The first time enter the article detail page works fine. This problem make me very confusing. Any suggestion is appreciate. This is my code of render the detail page:

```
PageStorageBucket pageStorageBucket = state.pageStorageBucket;
  Map<String, ScrollController> scrollControllers = state.scrollControllers;
  ScrollController scrollController = scrollControllers.length == 0 ? ScrollController() : scrollControllers[item.id]!;

  Widget navDetail(Item article) {
    return viewService.buildComponent("articledetail");
  }

  return PageStorage(
      bucket: pageStorageBucket,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('cruise'),
          brightness: Brightness.light, // or use Brightness.dark
          actions: [],
        ),
        body: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
          child: CupertinoScrollbar(
            isAlwaysShown: true,
            child:CustomScrollView(
            key: PageStorageKey(item.id),
            controller: scrollController,
            slivers: [
              SliverToBoxAdapter(child: navDetail(item)),
            ],
          )),
        ),
      ));
}
```

I am using PageStorage to store the postion of article read progress. When the first time entry artcile page, works fine, the second time, could  not scroll article detail page, from now on, it could not scroll. I did not known where is going wrong. And this is the article detial page code:

```
 return GestureDetector(
      onHorizontalDragStart: _onHorizontalDragStart,
      onHorizontalDragUpdate: _onHorizontalDragUpdate,
      onHorizontalDragEnd: _onHorizontalDragEnd,
      child: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
        ),
        color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: buildListView(item, context),
        ),
      ));
}
```

this is the article page build view code:

```
SingleChildScrollView buildListView(Item item, BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            InkWell(
              onTap: () => CommonUtils.launchUrl(item.link),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                child: Container(
                  child: Text(
                    item.title,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5!.copyWith(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            if (item.domain != "")
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () async {
                      navToChannelDetail();
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      item.domain,
                      style: getDomainStyle(item),
                    )),
              ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  children: <TextSpan>[
                    TextSpan(
                      text: item.author,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                    ),
                    TextSpan(
                      text: " ${String.fromCharCode(8226)} ",
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                    ),
                    TextSpan(
                      text: item.ago,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            if (item.content != "")
              Html(
                data: item.content,
                style: {
                  "body": Style(
                    fontSize: FontSize(19.0),
                  ),
                },
                onLinkTap: (String? url, RenderContext context, Map<String, String> attributes,  dom.Element? element){
                  CommonUtils.launchUrl(url);
              }),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          if (item.isFav == 1)
                            IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                              onPressed: () => touchFav("unfav", FavStatus.UNFAV),
                            ),
                          if (item.isFav != 1)
                            IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark),
                              onPressed: () => touchFav("fav", FavStatus.FAV),
                            ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "${item.favCount}",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          if (item.isUpvote == 1)
                            IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_up, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                              onPressed: () => touchUpvote("unupvote", UpvoteStatus.UNUPVOTE),
                            ),
                          if (item.isUpvote != 1)
                            IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
                              onPressed: () => touchUpvote("upvote", UpvoteStatus.UPVOTE),
                            ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "${item.upvoteCount}",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Feather.share_2,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => handleShare(id: item.id, title: item.title, postUrl: item.link),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
```

what should I do to fix this problem? After some debug, I found if I remove the:

```
key: PageStorageKey(item.id),
```

It could be scroll every time open the detail page but the reading progress did not remember. But I still not understand why would this happen.

new found: If I open the detail page and scroll imediately before the page load complete, every time I could scroll.If I open the page and wait a the page load complete, I could not scroll.